# Firebase AuthUI not working properly on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to implement the Firebase AuthUI for a dummy app following the course by google itself on udacity. I am not getting the same output as in the course itself and idk what to do exactly or what is going wrong. Below is the code i have written to start up the AuthUI:

```
private fun launchSignInFlow() {
    val providers =
        arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )
    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(
            providers
        ).build(), SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE
    )
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(
                TAG,
                "Successfully signed in user " +
                        "${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName}!"
            )
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Sign in unsuccessful ${response?.error?.errorCode}")
        }
    }
}
```

this is the output screen/ui that i get from this code
[image]

And this is what the output should be like according to the course i am following

[image]

What's worse is that even when i try to enter an email to the output i get, the screen gets stuck and does nothing at all. This is the link for the video of google for this specific task
https://youtu.be/JKZpZvbm3Bk

Comment: the problem is that the onActivityResult is not called after i enter the email and then i am stuck on that page

Comment: the problem was that the emulator is not connected to the internet, didn't see it at all and now it has been fixed and working properly, can any mod close the question? thank you